# how to render tabs Navigation and stack navigation at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i am trying to use stack navigation and tab navigation at the same time,i have created a stack navigator and tabs in my app.js files but whenever my app loads they are showing different pages at the same time and i don,t know how to resolve this issue. my app.js code is

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import IntroSlides from './src/screens/introslides/introslides';
import Dashboard from './src/screens/dashboard/dashboard';
import InboxScreen from '../screens/inbox/inbox';
import Favourites from '../screens/favourite/favourite';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
  intro: { screen: IntroSlides },
 }, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
     headerVisible: false,
  }
});
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
   // dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
   Inbox: { screen: InboxScreen },
   Favourites: { screen: Favourites }
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);    

export default App;
```

when the app loads both the stack shows pages at the same time ,any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to use tab navigator and stack navigator together:

```
const Stylelist = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
    }),
  },
  Register: {
    screen: RegisterScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
    }),
  },
  Home: {
    screen: TabNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Home',
        }),
      },
      Friends: {
        screen: FriendsScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'My Friends',
        }),
      },
    }),
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
    }),
  },
});

export default Stylelist;
```

Comment: i tried your code and now i am getting undefined is not a function (near'...(0,_reactNavigation.TabNavigator)...')

Comment: did you import it? In your code you have used `createBottomTabNavigator` and did not import it